# HTTP file post - where to begin

Tags: php, http

I am ordering products from a supplier using cURL.  I have a choice of receiving the orders by email, fairly straight forward, or via HTTP.  I want to use the HTTP delivery method to get the files delivered into a directory on my webserver.  I have asked the supplier to tell me more about the requirements for the HTTP and they are unable to give detail.  This suggests that it is something that can be setup entirely at my side, or they are not being forthcoming with information i will need.  I have asked them for examples of what other people have provided for the HTTP parameter and they have given me some examples.  Apparently most people have specified a URL to file level and not just directory level.  E.g. http://www.domain.co.uk/directory/listenLandmark.asmx  or .aspx or .ashx.  there are also some .php which is good as that is what i want to use.  Howeever, some have just given a directory level parameter.

I guess that if I use a php file, I will be able to handle the files delivered rather than just have to check manually to see if there is anything there.

Can somebody tell me what I need to do to get this started please.  The supplier is getting a 500 server error when trying to send/post file to me.  I have tried changing the permissions on a directory to allow public read and write and execute, but this has changed nothing and is presumably very bad practice anyway (??).

If somebody can give me a quick push in the right direction i would appreciate it (or is it the case that i need more information from the supplier before i can begin).

Comment: There's no such thing as "file level" or "directory level" in a URL. Just URLs which appear to have file names in them and URLs which do not. They all get handled by the server.

Comment: Alternatively you could just downvote me just because i don't know something you do - thanks

Comment: If I were to make massive assumptions about what sort of request is being made to your server, then the pointer I would give you would be: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: On the subject of assumptions: You shouldn't make them about where downvotes come from.

Comment: @quentin - excuse my terminology.  What i am saying is that some customers have specified a directory and others a file to handle the response.  How would i go about responsing to the receipt of files please.  Also what have people who have just specified a directory do at the server to allow for the reciept of files.  Thanks

Comment: @quentin - sorry i wasn't - our messages crossed in the post.  that was not directed at you.

Comment: Thanks I will look at the link you have provided - appreciate it.

Comment: "What i am saying is that some customers have specified a directory and others a file to handle the response" — No, they've just specified a URL. There are lots of ways to configure what piece of server side code will handle any given URL. Use whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure based on your description, but if you line of thought is that the url on your site they are making the http call to is where you want them to store files or anything like that, that almost certainly isn't the intended way for it to work.

That being said... I have no idea what service you are using, or exactly how they intend on it working.  But based on what you are describing it sounds like they are using a [webhook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) or interfacing in a similar way.  I'm guessing they are either making a http post call with all of the data for the files they need to send you, or they are making a http call with a list of URLs you can download the files from.

Since they can't provide you with any documentation (this is a giant red flag by the way), if I were you I would first find out what URL on your site they are trying to hit.  Once you find that out, then I would add a bunch of logging to see what headers, post data, and any query string they are sending. Once you have that data you should have a much better idea of how they are trying to interact with your site, and be able to make a game plan of how you will use that data to do whatever you need to do.

I hope that helps

Edit: (adding some example logging code)

You could do something like this to log your headers, get & post data, and any file upload.

```
<?php
$data = array("headers" => headers_list(), "post" => $_POST, "get" => $_GET, "file" => $_FILES);
$file = "/path/to/write/file.log.txt";
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
?>
```

Then it json encodes all the data (you could convert it all to a string in a different way if you like), and logs it to whatever file you want it to.  If you set `$file = "debug.txt"` it will just log to the same directory as the php file, or you can tell it to go to a specific directory if you like.  Then you just have to analyze the data and see what/where they are sending the data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It has given me a lot of guidance.  It did cross my mind that they might be trying to send links for the files to be downloaded from rather than the files.  The one thing they have asked for is the location that i want to use - i have given them /domain/theirconame/receive.php and now i need to write that file :-)

Comment: In my logging, what sort of php commands should i be looking at using please.  The other person answering mentioned the $_Files variable, what else should i try?  I would be pretty happy writing a php file that informs me what has happened, but i don't know how to gather what they have intially sent - what is the command or function to grab the content of the original call please.  Thanks.

Comment: I added an example to my answer